# Hooking into event when record deleted from custom plugin

Tags: events, records, hook

We are using a plugin that has created its own record for storing private messages. When deleting a message, it's calling the `delete()` method on an instance of the record, which appears to be using the `CActiveRecord`'s implementation of delete.

In `CActiveRecord::delete()`, it has a `$this->afterDelete()` method, which looks like it should be raising an `onAfterDelete` event, but I haven't had any luck hooking into it.

I've tried `craft()->on('pluginhandle_messageRecord.onAfterDelete', ...)` and `craft()->on('cActiveRecord.onAfterDelete', ...)`, but neither gets triggered.

Does anyone know the correct syntax for hooking into this event for this specific custom record?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's a Yii event, it doesn't follow the same `component.eventName` syntax that the other Craft events use and you can't use [craft->on()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/web/WebApp#on-detail) to register to listen to it.

Completely untested, but you should be able to use the traditional [Yii method](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/327/events-explained), though. Something like this:

```
$myRecord->onAfterDelete = function (Event $event) {
    // Do your thing.
};
```

Comment: It's good to know that craft()->on() won't work, otherwise I probably would've gone crazy trying different things.

So essentially the change would need to be made inside the plugin itself?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't clear on whether this one in the context of two plugins or just one.

Comment: The delete is occurring within a 3rd party plugin, and I want to be able to tie into that using a plugin we are developing. It sounds like that wouldn't be possible, since the change needs to be made directly in the 3rd party plugin.

Comment: Yeah, I think you'd need to fork the 3rd party plugin (or make a pull request) to expose that deletion for your plugin to use.